# howto prevent a html element from the default css?

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with html and css.
i have a html file with a css file attached and in the css file i have s.th. like:

```
    table { background: #fff; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin: 0 0 18px; border: 1px solid #ddd;  }

    table thead, table tfoot { background: #f5f5f5; }
    table thead tr th,
    table tfoot tr th,
    table tbody tr td,
    table tr td,
    table tfoot tr td { font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; text-align: left; }
    table thead tr th,
    table tfoot tr td { padding: 8px 10px 9px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; }
    table thead tr th:first-child, table tfoot tr td:first-child { border-left: none; }
    table thead tr th:last-child, table tfoot tr td:last-child { border-right: none; }

    table tbody tr.even,
    table tbody tr.alt { background: #f9f9f9; }
    table tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background: #f9f9f9; }
    table tbody tr td { color: #333; padding: 9px 10px; vertical-align: top; border: none; }
```

that is a default theme. its nice for all the tables.

but now i want to add a standart non css formated table in my web project so i write:

```
<table> ... </table>
```

this table gets formated with the css. what can i do, to **prevent this table getting formated with the css** just showing it with the normal default style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to give each table a separate class and then style them separately.

For example your html could be

```
<table class="example1>
  <tr>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="example2>
  <tr>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and your CSS could be

```
table.example1
{
  YOUR CSS
}    

table.example2
{
  YOUR CSS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> what can i do, to prevent this table getting formated with the css just showing it with the normal default style?

Change the selectors so they don't match the table.

There is no way to exclude an element from CSS rules if they have a selector that matches the element. If you can't prevent that in the first place then your only option is to write more rule-sets that apply different (specific) CSS to the element.

There is no "Reset to browser default" mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is to generic. You might change it to use classes.

For example, ale tables change to

```
table.styled {your csss here}
```

And then in code where you want your styled table use:

```
<table class="styled"> ... </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a class for the tables that you don't want to have the default appearance. Then apply the class to the tables that you want. You have to rewrite the default css rules. If not, the default rules will affect your table.